# Custom Code on Entity Lazy Load

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I've written a WPF desktop application, making use of Entity Framework to persist data (code first). I've got lazy loading enabled, which is working great.

For some of my entities, I need to implement some code every time it is instantiated through lazy loading. For example, I save some of my Datatables as lists in the database, and would like to convert these lists back to Datatables whenever the entity is lazy loaded.

I don't want to go through this conversion for the whole project necessarily (as not only can this be somewhat expensive, but for some projects the total objects can exceed available RAM). I also have all the 'custom' code that I'd like to run contained in one method. Lazy loading is therefore perfect, I just need to be able to run some custom code every time an entity is loaded.

So my question: is there any event (or other structure/pattern) that I can utilise or subscribe to so that I can run custom code every time an entity is initialised through lazy loading? I cannot use the parameterless constructor of said entity, as the properties haven't been loaded at that stage.

Comment: Is your method an instance method on the entity type already?  This would allow you to obtain the datatable with an instance of the given entity.  Is this not suitable for your purposes?

Comment: It is an instance method yes. I'm more struggling with finding the right 'trigger' that will run my instance method. For example something similar to the [OnDeserialized()] attribute when deserializing, except for lazy loading rather than deserializing.

Comment: Why do you need it to be present *immediately* upon object instantiation?  Is there something that prevents you from calling the method?

Comment: As you don't show code,I don't know if this applies to your case, but I usually create NotMapped properties with code in the get and set part to shape the data received from the database. For example, if in the DB I have a JSON serialized object, I create a property that returns that column deserialized in the getter, and stores the object serialized in the setter. If the object is complex enough, you can cache it in the getter.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I've implemented the necessary code in the appropriate get and set accessors. All properties are therefore being 'lazy loaded', which is in line with my requirements. My datatables therefore look as follows:

```
[NotMapped]
public DataTable MyTable
{
  get
  {
    //Deserialize MyTable from byte[] or string property, obtained from database.
  }
  set
  {
    //Serialize MyTable to a byte[] or string property, which is saved to database.
  }
}
```